# Yocto - Try to use Realtime Kernel Version

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, yocto, bitbake

### Try

Hello there

I tried to build a linux with yocto. Usually, I use the command `bitbake core-image-minimal` and have no errors. Now, I'd like to use the realtime kernel version.

So I added the following lines in build/conf/local.conf according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28025898/yocto-build-for-preempt-rt):

```
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel = "linux-yocto-rt"
COMPATIBLE_MACHINE_cyclone5 = "cyclone5"
COMPATIBLE_MACHINE_quilt-native = "cyclone5"
```

(I only changed the MACHINE to cyclone5 instead of beaglebone)

---

### Error

The command `bitbake core-image-rt` throws the following error:

```
Loading cache: 100% |########################################################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00
Loaded 1339 entries from dependency cache.
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies

Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION        = "1.32.0"
BUILD_SYS         = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING   = "universal"
TARGET_SYS        = "arm-poky-linux-gnueabi"
MACHINE           = "cyclone5"
DISTRO            = "poky"
DISTRO_VERSION    = "2.2"
TUNE_FEATURES     = "arm armv7a vfp  neon"
TARGET_FPU        = "softfp"
meta              
meta-poky         
meta-yocto-bsp    = "HEAD:73454473d7c286c41ee697f74052fed03c79f9f5"
meta-altera       = "HEAD:ab2ee2812670be650d6a722de08dff9bf05131f8"
meta-ines         = "master:819761a62e69ad09a14d877e2b9d9bbd5370b9e2"

Initialising tasks: 100% |###################################################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:02
NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
WARNING: stress-1.0.4-r0 do_fetch: Failed to fetch URL http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~apw/stress/stress-1.0.4.tar.gz, attempting MIRRORS if available
WARNING: linux-yocto-rt-4.8.3+gitAUTOINC+83110d94ed_4057556c04-r0 do_fetch: Failed to fetch URL git://git.yoctoproject.org/linux-yocto-4.8.git;branch=standard/preempt-rt/base;name=machine, attempting MIRRORS if available
WARNING: rt-tests-1_1.1-r0 do_fetch: Failed to fetch URL git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/rt-tests/rt-tests.git, attempting MIRRORS if available
ERROR: stress-1.0.4-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure: Fetch command export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-0nwPP5TSk1"; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh"; export PATH="/home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots-uninative/x86_64-linux/usr/bin:/home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/poky/scripts:/home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi:/home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots/cyclone5/usr/bin/crossscripts:/home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/sbin:/home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin:/home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/sbin:/home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/bin:/home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/poky/scripts:/home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/poky/bitbake/bin:/home/mc2/bin:/home/mc2/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"; export HOME="/home/mc2"; /usr/bin/env wget -t 2 -T 30 -nv --passive-ftp --no-check-certificate -P /home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/build/downloads 'http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~apw/stress/stress-1.0.4.tar.gz' --progress=dot -v failed with exit code 4, output:
--2017-11-08 17:29:51--  http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~apw/stress/stress-1.0.4.tar.gz
Resolving people.seas.harvard.edu (people.seas.harvard.edu)... 54.172.197.41
Connecting to people.seas.harvard.edu (people.seas.harvard.edu)|54.172.197.41|:80... failed: Connection refused.

ERROR: stress-1.0.4-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure for URL: 'http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~apw/stress/stress-1.0.4.tar.gz'. Unable to fetch URL from any source.
ERROR: stress-1.0.4-r0 do_fetch: Function failed: base_do_fetch
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/build/tmp/work/armv7a-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/stress/1.0.4-r0/temp/log.do_fetch.25139
ERROR: Task (/home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/build/../poky/meta/recipes-extended/stress/stress_1.0.4.bb:do_fetch) failed with exit code '1'
ERROR: linux-yocto-rt-4.8.3+gitAUTOINC+83110d94ed_4057556c04-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure: Fetch command export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-0nwPP5TSk1"; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh"; export PATH="/home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots-uninative/x86_64-linux/usr/bin:/home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/poky/scripts:/home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi:/home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots/cyclone5/usr/bin/crossscripts:/home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/sbin:/home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin:/home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/sbin:/home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/bin:/home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/poky/scripts:/home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/poky/bitbake/bin:/home/mc2/bin:/home/mc2/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"; export HOME="/home/mc2"; LANG=C git -c core.fsyncobjectfiles=0 clone --bare --mirror git://git.yoctoproject.org/linux-yocto-4.8.git /home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/build/downloads/git2/git.yoctoproject.org.linux-yocto-4.8.git --progress failed with exit code 128, output:
Cloning into bare repository '/home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/build/downloads/git2/git.yoctoproject.org.linux-yocto-4.8.git'...
fatal: unable to connect to git.yoctoproject.org:
git.yoctoproject.org[0: 140.211.169.56]: errno=Connection refused


ERROR: linux-yocto-rt-4.8.3+gitAUTOINC+83110d94ed_4057556c04-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure for URL: 'git://git.yoctoproject.org/linux-yocto-4.8.git;branch=standard/preempt-rt/base;name=machine'. Unable to fetch URL from any source.
ERROR: linux-yocto-rt-4.8.3+gitAUTOINC+83110d94ed_4057556c04-r0 do_fetch: Function failed: base_do_fetch
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/build/tmp/work/cyclone5-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-yocto-rt/4.8.3+gitAUTOINC+83110d94ed_4057556c04-r0/temp/log.do_fetch.25135
ERROR: Task (/home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/build/../poky/meta/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-yocto-rt_4.8.bb:do_fetch) failed with exit code '1'
ERROR: rt-tests-1_1.1-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure: Fetch command export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-0nwPP5TSk1"; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh"; export PATH="/home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots-uninative/x86_64-linux/usr/bin:/home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/poky/scripts:/home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi:/home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots/cyclone5/usr/bin/crossscripts:/home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/sbin:/home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin:/home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/sbin:/home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/bin:/home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/poky/scripts:/home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/poky/bitbake/bin:/home/mc2/bin:/home/mc2/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"; export HOME="/home/mc2"; LANG=C git -c core.fsyncobjectfiles=0 clone --bare --mirror git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/rt-tests/rt-tests.git /home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/build/downloads/git2/git.kernel.org.pub.scm.utils.rt-tests.rt-tests.git --progress failed with exit code 128, output:
Cloning into bare repository '/home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/build/downloads/git2/git.kernel.org.pub.scm.utils.rt-tests.rt-tests.git'...
fatal: unable to connect to git.kernel.org:
git.kernel.org[0: 147.75.205.195]: errno=Connection refused
git.kernel.org[1: 2604:1380:2000:f000::7]: errno=Network is unreachable


ERROR: rt-tests-1_1.1-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure for URL: 'git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/rt-tests/rt-tests.git'. Unable to fetch URL from any source.
ERROR: rt-tests-1_1.1-r0 do_fetch: Function failed: base_do_fetch
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/build/tmp/work/armv7a-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/rt-tests/1_1.1-r0/temp/log.do_fetch.25136
ERROR: Task (/home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/build/../poky/meta/recipes-rt/rt-tests/rt-tests_1.1.bb:do_fetch) failed with exit code '1'
WARNING: hwlatdetect-1_1.1-r0 do_fetch: Failed to fetch URL git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/rt-tests/rt-tests.git, attempting MIRRORS if available
ERROR: hwlatdetect-1_1.1-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure: Fetch command export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-0nwPP5TSk1"; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh"; export PATH="/home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots-uninative/x86_64-linux/usr/bin:/home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/poky/scripts:/home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi:/home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots/cyclone5/usr/bin/crossscripts:/home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/sbin:/home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin:/home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/sbin:/home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/bin:/home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/poky/scripts:/home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/poky/bitbake/bin:/home/mc2/bin:/home/mc2/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"; export HOME="/home/mc2"; LANG=C git -c core.fsyncobjectfiles=0 clone --bare --mirror git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/rt-tests/rt-tests.git /home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/build/downloads/git2/git.kernel.org.pub.scm.utils.rt-tests.rt-tests.git --progress failed with exit code 128, output:
Cloning into bare repository '/home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/build/downloads/git2/git.kernel.org.pub.scm.utils.rt-tests.rt-tests.git'...
fatal: unable to connect to git.kernel.org:
git.kernel.org[0: 147.75.205.195]: errno=Connection refused
git.kernel.org[1: 2604:1380:2000:f000::7]: errno=Network is unreachable


ERROR: hwlatdetect-1_1.1-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure for URL: 'git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/rt-tests/rt-tests.git'. Unable to fetch URL from any source.
ERROR: hwlatdetect-1_1.1-r0 do_fetch: Function failed: base_do_fetch
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/build/tmp/work/armv7a-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/hwlatdetect/1_1.1-r0/temp/log.do_fetch.25140
ERROR: Task (/home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/build/../poky/meta/recipes-rt/rt-tests/hwlatdetect_1.1.bb:do_fetch) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 1353 tasks of which 1349 didn't need to be rerun and 4 failed.

Summary: 4 tasks failed:
  /home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/build/../poky/meta/recipes-extended/stress/stress_1.0.4.bb:do_fetch
  /home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/build/../poky/meta/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-yocto-rt_4.8.bb:do_fetch
  /home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/build/../poky/meta/recipes-rt/rt-tests/rt-tests_1.1.bb:do_fetch
  /home/mc2/XYZ_Project_Verification/yocto/build/../poky/meta/recipes-rt/rt-tests/hwlatdetect_1.1.bb:do_fetch
Summary: There were 4 WARNING messages shown.
Summary: There were 12 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

---

I already checked the bb file. There is a linux-yocto_rt_4.8.bb file in yocto/poky/meta/recipes-kernel/linux

---

Any hints or suggestions how to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well you look like you are habing problems connecting to git repositories. Are you sure you have an internet connection while you are attempting to fetch the repositories?

Answer (score 2):

your error seems to fetching problem. Please connect `internet` it will solve your prblem.