# How to build Real time image with yocto?

Tags: raspberry-pi3, yocto

I am new to Yocto and trying to build RT image with yocto.

I am using Ubuntu version: 20.04

yocto branch: thud

And I built minimal image kernel version.

VERSION = 4

PATCHLEVEL = 14

SUBLEVEL = 112

But unable to find patch-4.14.112-rtXX.patch patch in this path to make it RT image:
(https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt/)

Issues:

1. How to find what kernal version will build by bitbake before giving "bitbake core-image-minimal" command? (Because some of the rt patches are not present in above link and while applying, version of patches should match?)
2. How to apply PREEMPT_RT patches?

Referred Document:
https://archive.fosdem.org/2018/schedule/event/rt_linux_with_yocto/attachments/slides/2684/export/events/attachments/rt_linux_with_yocto/slides/2684/Yocto_RT.pdf

In above pdf till Building minimal image steps were completed.

Answer (score 0):

1. To know the yocto kernel version you are using, just type bitbake -e virtual/kernel | grep "^PV"
2. You need to use `linux-yocto-rt` kenrel instead `linux-yocto`. You can do this by editing conf/local.conf:

   PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel = "linux-yocto-rt"

- [Yocto build for preempt_rt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28025898/yocto-build-for-preempt-rt)
- [Real-Time Linux](https://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/real-time-linux)